# How do i call worker thread in a same class (C++, MFC)?

Tags: c++, mfc

Here is my code which contains error:

```
void ClassA::init()
{
    HANDLE hThread;
    data thread;          // "thread" is an object of struct data

    hThread = CreateThread(NULL, 0, C1::threadfn, &thread, 0, NULL);
}

DWORD WINAPI ClassA::threadfn(LPVOID lpParam)
{   
    data *lpData = (data*)lpParam;
}
```

Error:

```
error C3867: 'ClassA::threadfn': function call missing argument list; use '&ClassA::threadfn' to create a pointer to member
```

What is the proper way to make the worker thread working in a single class?

Comment: Can you fix the spelling errors? The C1::threadfn can't cause a error for ClassA::thradfn'.

Answer (score 5):

The thread creation functions are not aware of C++ classes; as such, your thread entry point must be either a static class member function, or a non-member function. You can pass in the `this` pointer as the `lpvThreadParam` parameter to the `CreateThread()` function, then have the static or non-member entry point function simply call the `threadfn()` function via that pointer.

If the `threadfn()` function *is* static, then make sure you put `&` before `C1::threadfn`.

Here's a simple example:

```
class MyClass {
  private:
    static DWORD WINAPI trampoline(LPVOID pSelf);
    DWORD threadBody();
  public:
    HANDLE startThread();
}

DWORD WINAPI MyClass::trampoline(LPVOID pSelf) {
  return ((MyClass)pSelf)->threadBody();
}

DWORD MyClass::threadBody() {
  // Do the actual work here
}

HANDLE MyClass::startThread() {
  return CreateThread(NULL, 0, &MyClass::trampoline, (LPVOID)this, 0, NULL);
}
```

Comment: could you provide me a correct one because i still getting errors

Answer (score 1):

You're using MFC, according to the tags. `CreateThread` is the Win32 C API, you should look at `CWinThread` instead.

Comment: If I use CThread, how do i pass multiple data into the thread? Because according to MSDN, CWinThread* AfxBeginThread(
   CRuntimeClass* pThreadClass,
   int nPriority = THREAD_PRIORITY_NORMAL,
   UINT nStackSize = 0,
   DWORD dwCreateFlags = 0,
   LPSECURITY_ATTRIBUTES lpSecurityAttrs = NULL 
); has no LPVOID lpParam.

Comment: You derive a class from `CWinThread`. Extra data simply becomes members, accessed via the `this` pointer. No casting or other pointer wizardry needed.

Answer (score 0):

Follow the advice in the warning error, then this should work provided the member function `threadfn` is `static`.

Answer (score 0):

What happens if you do what the error says?

```
CreateThread(NULL, 0, &C1::threadfn, &thread, 0, NULL);  // now passing pointer
```

This assumes that `threadfn()` is static.