# C++ class: pointer to a non-static func

Tags: c++, multithreading, class, visual-c++, function-pointers

This is my [last question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7490219/c-class-object-that-creates-thread-pointer-to-the-function-access-violatio). I try to improve my class Thread.
Constructor receives pointer to the function, that must run in a new thread.

```
class Thread { 
    public:
     Thread(void (*p)()) {
        pf=p;
      }
     ~Thread () {}
    void StartThread() {
     hThread = (HANDLE)_beginthreadex( NULL, 0, ThreadProc, NULL, 0, &threadID); 
    }
    private: 
     void (*pf)();
     HANDLE hThread; 
     unsigned threadID;
     static unsigned WINAPI ThreadProc(LPVOID lpParam) {
      (*pf)(); //error C2597 illegal reference to non-static member
      return 0; 
     }
    };
```

In ThreadProc I need to call TimerFunc.

```
void TimerFunc () {
    i++;
}
```

Example of usage this class:

```
Thread *timer; 
timer = new Thread(TimerFunc);  
timer->StartThread();
```

So it doesn't work. 
Please somebody tell me, if this class is foolish. 
May be it is a bad idea to send pointer to func which is situated outside class??
Thank you.

Thanks very much for your advices! 
Now it works!

```
class Thread { 
public:
    Thread(void (*p)()) {
        gg.pf=p;
    }
    ~Thread ();
    void StartThread() {
     hThread = (HANDLE)_beginthreadex( NULL, 0, ThreadProc, this, 0, &threadID); 
    }
private: 
    struct mm {
        Thread *pThread; 
        void (*pf)();
    } gg;
    HANDLE hThread; 
    unsigned threadID; 
    static unsigned WINAPI ThreadProc(LPVOID lpParam) {
        mm hh; 
        hh.pThread=static_cast<Thread*> (lpParam);
        hh.pf=hh.pThread->gg.pf;
        hh.pf();
        return 0; 
    }
};
```

What do you think? Is it correct choice?

Comment: Can you say what does not work about it? What are you seeing?

Comment: I see error C2597 illegal reference to non-static member pf

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the outhers pointed out, the problem is that a static method cannot access non-static members. The usual way to do something like this is to pass the object as parameter to the thread start routine, e.g.:

```
class Thread { 
public:
    Thread(void (*p)()) {
        pf=p;
    }
    ~Thread () {}
    void StartThread() {
        // Pass this as argument to ThreadProc
        hThread = (HANDLE)_beginthreadex( NULL, 0, ThreadProc, this, 0, &threadID); 
    }
private: 
    void (*pf)();
    HANDLE hThread; 
    unsigned threadID;
    static unsigned WINAPI ThreadProc(LPVOID lpParam) {
        // Get the passed Thread object
        Thread *pThread = static_cast<Thread*> (lpParam);
        pThread->pf();
        return 0; 
    }
};
```

Comment: but it still doesn't work. Error in this string  pThread->*pf();
error C2597: illegal reference to non-static member 'sample::Thread::pf

Comment: I corrected the code. The problem was using `->*`, which is the pointer to member operator. Instead, simply `->` is required, since `pf` is not a member function of `Thread`

Comment: Thank you for your correction. I have updated my post. Can you check please?

Comment: Those are the short forms. Correct is also `(*pThread->pf)();` and calling Thread's constructor with `timer = new Thread(&TimerFunc);`

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that ThreadProc is defined as static, meaning it is not bound to an object. Then, you try to use a class member that is not static and must be bound to an object.

The typical way to overcome this is to pass in a structure to your thread via a void* pointer that the creation function accepts. This structure should contain the arguments that you need to make the thing go. Somewhere in it, you should have a pointer to the class that you're trying to bind the objects to. Then, refer to pf via this pointer.

Comment: @Girl_Developer That certainly works. If I know that the only data the threading function will need is a pointer to the class, this is how I handle it. Sometimes, the thread function needs for data, in which case I create a nested class or struct in the outer class that contains all the data that the static thread function will need.

Answer (score 1):

Your `ThreadProc` member function is a static member function. Therefore it doesn't have access to any nonstatic members or member functions, including `pf`. I am seeing why you decided to make `TreadProc` a static member function - because then you'd be able to pass it to `_beginthreadex` as a plain function pointer.

Well, as you see, this approach has its problems. Fixing this problem is not trivial. You can check [boost thread](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/doc/html/thread.html) implementation and see how they have done it.